# Care less and less care

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the difference between this ones?

Can the first one mean that she doesn't stop caring a little less as before or can it be related to the second one not first one?

> She doesn't care ***less***

> She doesn't ***less*** care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comment thread is getting confusing, so I'll just lay it out here. The correct phrase is *she couldn't care less*. It literally means that she cares so little, it would be impossible for her to care any less. *Couldn't* is being used to say that it's *impossible*, she is *unable* to care less than she currently does. She's at an extreme of not caring. Even if she wanted to care less, she couldn't.

*She doesn't care* is a simple way of saying... well, that she doesn't care. You could say *she doesn't care at all* or something like that, to emphasise how little she cares.

These two phrases have basically the same meaning, but *couldn't care less* tends to imply detachment or complete disinterest. It could feel much more critical, depending on the context.

(Some people say *could care less*, which is a corruption of *couldn't care less*. **Literally** it has the opposite meaning, but it's **intended** to mean the same as *couldn't care less*. So if you ever see someone use it, that's (probably) what they mean.)

Answer (score 1):

"She doesn't care less." as an isolated sentence makes little if any sense. It could be used as part of a comparison, such as:

> She doesn't care less than I do.

The sentence "She doesn't less care" is grammatically incorrect, and has no obvious meaning.

However, the sentence:

> She couldn't care less.

is an idiom. It means "She doesn't care at all" or "She has no opinion on the matter." This idion is always used with "couldn't"  never wqith "doesn't". See [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couldn%27t%20care%20less) which also says that "She could care less" can be used with the same meaning, but that is not mthe form IO know.

Comment: And what about the second one with what I'm guessing?

Comment: @Boyep if by "the second one" you mean the second sentence in he question ("She doesn't less care") That is just wrong and has no meaning at all in standard English. I don't understand what you mean by "with what I'm guessing".

Comment: Okay, and how would you say she can't stop caring a little less?

Comment: Do you mean that she can't stop herself from caring less (=she does care less than before), or that she doesn't stop caring (=she cares as much as before)?

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I mean (she cares as much as before).

Comment: In that case, it's _She doesn't care **any** less_

Comment: I couldn't care less, in American English is "I could care less" (with exactly the same meaning as "I couldn't care less")

Comment: @Kate Bunting what if to be said "She care less", then, is it still remaining that she doesn't care at all or she cares less than before?

Comment: It has to be "She _cares_ less", but that doesn't mean very much on its own. You could say "She cares less than she used to,"  or "She cares less than you do."